# jQuery event for checked radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener, onchange

Is there any event, to append to the following listener, that will tell me if a radio button is already clicked?

```
var budgetType;
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="import_export"]', function() {
    console.log($(this))
    budgetType = $(this).val();
});
```

My problem is that, on page reload, if the radio box is already checked, the `change` listener won't work, and I didn't find any listener that will help me with that issue.

Any ideas?

### Update

I'm aware that I could write an `if/else` syntax and see which is checked, but I was wondering if there is any other listener that I could append to `change` one, and avoid writing that extra syntax.

http://jsfiddle.net/S93XB/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')
```

Try this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/rU2Fc/

or try this one

```
$('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', true);
```

Try this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/rU2Fc/1/

It will work, you can execute this onload to get the first value and use it in an if else block.

Comment: Yea, I'm aware that I could check for the checked input with an if/else syntax, but I'm rather looking for an listener that could go next to `change`

Comment: You know radio buttons have true false condition, either checked or unchecked, so why not you use `click` instead of `change`? :)

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the change event on load:

```
var budgetType;
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="import_export"]', function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
    console.log($(this).val()+" "+isChecked);
    budgetType = $(this).val();
});
$('input[name="import_export"]:checked').trigger('change');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eLGaB/

Comment: Ok, this I like! Using `trigger`  is a nice idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('input[type=radio]').is(':checked')
```

Or

```
$('input[type=radio]').prop('checked') === true;
```

Or

```
$('input[type=radio]').attr('checked') === 'checked';
```